# Convert from integer to byte array using encoding/binary using Go based on endianness

Tags: go

I have written the function `FromBytes` which converts bytes to integer format and passes it to `IP4()` based on endianness as follows:

```
 type IP4 uint32

 func FromBytes(ip []byte) IP4 {
       var pi IP4
       buf := bytes.NewReader(ip)
       if <little endian>
            err := binary.Read(buf, binary.LittleEndian, &pi)
       else
            err := binary.Read(buf, binary.BigEndian, &pi)
       if err != nil {
               fmt.Println("binary.Read failed:", err)
        }
       return IP4(pi)
}
```

I need help writing a function which will convert from integer to bytes:

```
func (ip IP4) Octets() (a, b, c, d byte) {
    if <little endian>
        // code to convert from integer to bytes for little endian
    } else {
        // code to convert from integer to bytes for big endian
    }
    return
}
```

Comment: Endianness doesn't matter in this case, just `return ip[0], ip[1], ip[2], ip[3]` assuming you want network order for the individual bytes. The endianness only matters for the native integer representation.

Comment: what about FromBytes() does endiness check is needed. what is wrong with putting endianess check?

Comment: In `FromBytes` the endianness check is appropriate, because you're taking a network order integer, stored in an array of bytes, and decoding it into a native integer type. However, doing it again for the `Octets` method would potentially result in double reordering on a little endian arch.

Comment: You mean: a, b, c, d = byte(ip>>24), byte(ip>>16), byte(ip>>8), byte(ip) with this solution I have tested. for bigendian, I am getting the octacts in reverse order. .

Comment: sorry, I was completely confused. Disregard everything. IP addresses are normally represented in network (big endian) order, so always read the `buf` with `BigEndian`, and use logical bitshifts like you do in your last comment, which operate on significant digits not on byte order.

Answer (score 5):

```
b := make([]byte, 4) // 4 bytes for uint32.

binary.BigEndian.PutUint32(b, uint32(yourIP4))

// and

binary.LittleEndian.PutUint32(b, uint32(yourIP4))
```

Comment: getting error cannot use ip (type IP4) as type uint32 in argument to binary.LittleEndian.PutUint32

Comment: @ravi_ss Edited the answer to add a uint32() cast around your IP4 values.